# Jira - how to get Sprint information

Tags: jira

I'm looking for a way to get sprint information from JIRA using RESTful API.
I could not find the information in JIRA documentation. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize asking about a RESTful API was general computing. And here I thought making web service requests over HTTP was in the programming realm....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the jira-python is here http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
if using another language it should be similar to :

```
# Get the sprints in a specific board
board_id = 441
print("GreenHopper board: %s (%s)" % (boards[0].name, board_id))
sprints = gh.sprints(board_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be in the JIRA Agile documentation since sprints come with JIRA Agile. But it's not. The best source of info at the moment is to look at the source of the jira-python library. Various REST methods are used in there to access JIRA Agile.